# Regex for people names PHP

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I am using this regex to make sure that names can only contain letters, apostrophe or hyphen.

```
Validator::extend('people_names', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return preg_match("^[a-zA-Z-'\s]+$^", $value);
```

When I use this [tool](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/h7p) to check if the regex is correct, it shows its correct, but in my form when I test an input starting with digits or any other characters like `123name` or `#$#$name` it passes while it should not. An input with letters then digits like `name123` is rejected.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP `preg_` functions need to start with `/^` and end with `$/`.

Try this:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-'\s]+$/", $value);
```

Comment: In PHP, you do not have to *to start with `/^` and end with `$/`*, just `preg_` functions require a regex delimiter.

Comment: `^` and `$` are *regex anchors* that are part of the *pattern*, the regex delimiters are `/` leading and trailing symbols here.

Answer (score 1):

In your regex `^[a-zA-Z-'\s]+$^`, you are only checking if the string ends with a letter by using the `$` at the end, but the `^` at the beginning is used here asthe regex delimiter, since it's also at the end.

I'd recommend using another string delimiter, such as `#` or `/` :

`preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z-'\s]+$#", $value)` should work.